Why can we use RMSE as a proxy for the effect size of a VAR or Granger Causality?
My question here follows a previous question by me here: Is there a meaningful option to compute something like an effect size for Granger Causality?. In this previous question I asked for options to compute a proxy for an effect size of Granger causality (GC) results. This is because GC only yields p-values which themselves cannot be interpreted as effect size.
Context of my question: I computed GC between various pairs of time-series data and now, as suggested in the link above, used the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE). My procedure to obtain the RMSE is as follows.

First, train a VAR on the first 80% of my time-series.
Second, I took the last 20% of my time-series of interest as test data on which I run the prediction of the model.
Finally, instead of computing the RMSE, I computed the RMSE in percentage, as for example outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325114/how-to-express-root-mean-squared-error-as-a-percentage. The percentage RMSE was computed using the last 20% of the time-series (test data) and the 20% of predicted values for the same.

The reason for computing the percentage RMSE is as follows: The original time-series data was non-stationary and required first-order differencing. Therefore, the time-series’ values became very small so that the RMSE results no longer allow an easy or straightforward interpretation.
Results: The percentage RMSE results are small. All are below 8%, and most range between 2-5%. The very low percentage RMSE values indicate that my VAR model indeed offers a good prediction. I also observed that the percentage RMSE values do not correspond with the level or value of the p-values. That is, lower percentage RMSE values do not necessarily go along with lower p-values, as shown in the plot below.

Question: I still cannot fully understand why RMSE can serve as a proxy for the effect size of GC. I understand that a lower RMSE means that our model provided a better prediction than another instance of the same model (where the VAR used two different time-series) with a higher RMSE.
But how can I better articulate the usage of RMSE as a proxy for effect size concerning GC in a scientific paper?
Edit (further information): I would like to provide further results of my RMSE and percentage RMSPE empirical findings. Generally, I observe that lower p-values of GC follow a hierarchy across brain regions. Without going into details, I see that p-values increase as I go up a hierarchy where I expect the effect of GC to decrease. Phrased even more simply, p-values become non-significant (p > 0.05) where I expect GC to fade away.
However, and now comes an important point, the RMSE values do not follow this hierarchy. Generally, RMSE values are surprisingly low, meaning that the model apparently predicts better than I ever expected.
Conclusion: Based on these findings, I would conclude that the usage of RMSE as an effect size for GC does not work in my specific case to underline that lower p-values are related to stronger GC effects. Nonetheless, as I understand it, I could use RMSE (or percentage RMSE) to further underline that my VAR model works well, providing some evidence that the VAR is doing well what it is meant do to. Would you agree with all of the above?

RMSE results should be equal for level and first-differenced series because the forecast errors are equal. How did you manage to get different values? If today the temperature is 20°C and you forecast tomorrow's temperature to be 22°C but it turns out to be 23°C, you are off by 1°. This is equivalent to forecasting the temperature increase of 2° when the actual increase is 3°, again off by exactly 1°. The two must match exactly.

My original time-series values range from ~0.2 to ~3. After differencing (first-order difference), both time-series fluctuate from around -0.05 to 0.05. I use the differenced time-series in the forecasting and compare the forecast with the differenced time-series. Therefore, the values remain extremely small (compared to the original values of the non-differenced time-series). Does that make sense?

No, it does not make sense to me. Does my example makes sense to you?

Is it possible to quickly discuss this via a chat here? It might be easier, maybe I got confused over something....

We could try if you are around.

Sure, how does it work? I assume that you can contact me (I think you are a mod and you can do that?). I am online.

I am not a mod (no diamond next to my name), but anyone can enter the chat. You may start here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=stats.stackexchange.com Unfortunately, I am on the move yet again...

Thanks Richard. I created a room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/153926/rmse-as-effect-size-for-a-var-or-granger-causality?tab=general

These have been a few hectic days, and there are more hectic ones ahead. Sorry to lead you on (though not intentionally).

No problem, Richard. Just let me know when you are free.
